# How to select data from VARIABLE table in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking for way to read data from user define type variable and when I do that:

[image: my code]

I get this error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@mytabe".

Code:

```
CREATE TYPE CD_info AS TABLE
                       (
                           sestem_id nvarchar(10),
                           national_id nvarchar(14),
                           employee_name nvarchar(80),
                           salary money, 
                           department nvarchar(80)
                       )

CREATE PROCEDURE Insert_CDInfo
    @mytabe CD_info READONLY , 
    @monthes int,
    @TBname NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @insertSql VARCHAR(MAX) = 'insert into'  + @TBname +'(sestem_id, national_id,employee_name,salary,department)'+
        'select  top (1000000)  sestem_id,national_id,employee_name,salary,department from '+  [@mytabe]  

   EXEC  @insertSql 
END
```

Thanks

Comment: the error is Must declare the scalar variable "@mytabe".

Comment: the @mytabe is a variable it's data table

Comment: Ok . thanks for your monsion MENTION

Comment: Please don't use images for code, data or errors. Use formatted text.

Answer (score 3):

The table valued parameter is only available in the scope in which it is declared so you cannot use it within the dynamic SQL `EXECUTE` statement.

Instead of `EXECUTE`, use a parameterized SQL statement and execute with `sp_executesql`. This will allow you to pass the TVP to the inner scope of the dynamic SQL as a parameter. For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Insert_CDInfo
    @mytabe CD_info READONLY , 
    @monthes int,
    @TBname NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @insertSql nvarchar(MAX) = 
          N'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TBname) +' (sestem_id, national_id,employee_name,salary,department) '
        + N'SELECT TOP (1000000) sestem_id,national_id,employee_name,salary,department FROM @mytabe;'; 

    EXEC sp_executesql
        @insertSql
        , N'@mytabe CD_info READONLY'
        , @mytabe = @mytabe;
END
GO
```